# Escape special characters like + in Java

Tags: java, postgresql, escaping, psql, apache-commons

I want to escape all the special characters in a String.

**Input String:**     `Foo+Bar`

**Output String:** `Foo\+Bar`

So the `+` should be escaped to `\+`. This is required as I have to pass the resulted string to Postgres SQL as a regex pattern, so if I pass just `+` it is causing an exception there.

I have tried using the [apache-commons:commons-text](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text/1.8)  but that does not escape the `+` in the `String`

Answer (score 0):

If you modify the customized pattern, `special` below, this may do what you want.

```
        String special = "([\\[\\]()+*.])";
        String str = "This is (a test) of [how to ] escape things like +, *, and .";
        str = str.replaceAll(special, "\\\\$1");
        System.out.println(str);
```

- The `$1` is a backreference to the special character that matched.
- The `\\\\` is required to escape the escape to allow a slash to appear in the substitution.

Comment: This works but for this, I will have to have all the special characters in the `special` String?

Comment: Yes.  You can also use *Michal Kordas* idea to escape the entire string if this is for regex?

Comment: Okay. I tried the  Pattern#quote(String)  but that did not work for `+`. Yes this string will be used as a regex in the database layer i.e `psql`

Comment: @VGR  I'm sure I did.  It was just an example.  I figured the OP could tailor it since I didn't know what the purpose of the escaping was for.

Answer (score 0):

There is method to do it in plain Java. Use [Pattern#quote(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) to escape all regex-related characters.

Comment: Yes.  That simply encapsulates the string between  a `\Q` and `\E`.  I wasn't sure that is what the OP wanted.

Comment: I tried this but that does not change the `+` to `\+` as expected.

Comment: @RajRajeshwarSinghRathore  It doesn't change any of the special characters if  you're looking for visual clarification.  It just isolates them from the regex engine.

Comment: Okay but the string will not be used in Java as a regex but will be passed in a psql query where it will be treated as a regex. So the escaping is required for that purpose.

Comment: Then it sounds like you need to escape the String to bypass `psql` to get to the regex parser.  It is probably because `psql` doesn't understand the `\Q` and `\E` meaning.  But it's just a guess.  I can't offer any other solutions.

Comment: `\Q...\E` is specific to java regex and won't work in PostgreSQL. `Pattern.quote` quotes according to Java regex too, so I'm not sure I'd want to rely on that. After a quick search the `q` [flag](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html#POSIX-EMBEDDED-OPTIONS-TABLE) makes the rest of the regex be interpreted as literal characters in postgresql, and can be used as an inline flag `(?q)` if necessary

Comment: Can you provide any link to the `q` flag of PostgresSQL

Comment: @RajRajeshwarSinghRathore https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html#POSIX-EMBEDDED-OPTIONS-TABLE

Comment: I'm not sure `(?q)` quite cuts it actually. I assume you only want part of the regex to be interpreted as literal characters (otherwise not much reason to use a regex), but it looks like those flags can only be specified as the start of a regex and will affect all of it